# New column with window by mean

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I need to write a service that prints customers whose average cost is greater than 500.00.

We have two datasets, the first stores the customers and their chatbots used that month.

```
df_bots_used = pd.DataFrame({'customer_id': [7494212,7494212,1475185,6946725,6946725],
                                 'chatbot_id': [1000,2000,3000,4000,5000],
                                 'chatbot_type': ['Pesquisa de satisfação','Confirmação de agendamento','Negociação de dívida','Segunda via de fatura','Pesquisa de satisfação']})
```

The second keeps the collection of amounts of chatbots:

```
df_bots = pd.DataFrame({'chatbot_id': [1000,2000,3000,4000,5000],
                            'cost': [200.0,100.0,1000.0,50.0,400.0]})
```

I would like to create a new column with a window function by `mean` at the moment of the run the `merge()` function in these datasets.

With this command:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.merge(df_bots,df_bots_used, on='chatbot_id').rolling(1).mean()
```

But the result is:

```
    chatbot_id  cost    customer_id
0   1000.0      200.0   7494212.0
1   2000.0      100.0   7494212.0
2   3000.0      1000.0  1475185.0
3   4000.0      50.0    6946725.0
4   5000.0      400.0   6946725.0
```

I would get this result, with a window of means by `customer_id`

```
    chatbot_id  cost    customer_id   window_mean
0   1000        200.0   7494212       150.0
1   2000        100.0   7494212       150.0
2   3000        1000.0  1475185       1000.0
3   4000        50.0    6946725       225.0
4   5000        400.0   6946725       225.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`df.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html):

```
res = pd.merge(df_bots,df_bots_used, on='chatbot_id')[['chatbot_id','cost','customer_id']]     
res['window_mean'] = res.groupby('customer_id')['cost'].transform('mean')
```

Output:

```
   chatbot_id    cost  customer_id  window_mean
0        1000   200.0      7494212        150.0
1        2000   100.0      7494212        150.0
2        3000  1000.0      1475185       1000.0
3        4000    50.0      6946725        225.0
4        5000   400.0      6946725        225.0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df4=df_bots_used.set_index(['chatbot_id']).combine_first(df_bots.set_index(['chatbot_id'])).reset_index()).drop(columns=['chatbot_type'])
df4['window_mean']= df4.groupby('customer_id')['cost'].transform('mean')



chatbot_id  cost     customer_id    window_mean
0   1000       200.0     7494212         150.0
1   2000       100.0     7494212         150.0
2   3000       1000.0    1475185         1000.0
3   4000       50.0      6946725         225.0
4   5000       400.0     6946725         225.0
```

Answer (score 0):

We can create it from `df_bots_used`

```
#DF HERE IS AFTER MERGE 
DF['window_mean']= DF.groupby('chatbot_id').cost.transform('mean')
```